# Curve25519 simple key exchange approach

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, key-exchange

What is a simple approach in Curve25519 key exchange in basic steps?

Comment: Have you looked at https://cr.yp.to/ecdh.html ? What's not clear in it ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Alice and Bob choose their secret scalars $a,b \in \{0,1\}^{|p|}$.
2. They compute their public keys $Ga$ and $Gb$ and send the public key to the other.
3. Alice computes the shared key $k = \text{kdf}(Gba)$ and Bob computes the shared key $k = \text{kdf}(Gab)$.

---

4. They can use this established key $k$ as their shared symmetric key. I.e. Use it as the key for AES-PMAC-SIV to send variable-length messages that are both authenticated end encrypted.

---

Eve is allowed to learn all public keys and ciphertexts. Assuming that at least the Computation Diffie-Hellman and Discrete Logarithm problems are hard, then she cannot recover the shared key.

Comment: Careful!  The secret _scalars_ are _not_ arbitrary 256-bit strings, or arbitrary 253-bit strings if $p$ is the order of the standard base point and $|p| = \lceil\log_2 p\rceil$; they are rather multiples of 8 between $2^{254}$ and $2^{255}$.  Not clear on your notation $Ga$; is this supposed to be the scalar multiplication of the base point $G$ by the scalar $a$?  If so, why the half-multiplicative half-exponential notation $Gb^a$?

Comment: Er I mixed notations indeed. Editing. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: As for the scalar point details I'd rather not assume clamping and cofactors. See Decaf/Ristretto. Ideally the scalar is the full 256-bit.

Comment: You can choose to use Decaf or Ristretto, but most applications of Curve25519 don't.  If you want to call the uniform random 256-bit string the _private key_, that's fine; it's just not the _scalar_ that is used in practice.

Comment: Okay. Should I say $F^*_p$ too?

Comment: Doesn't sound right. I'm too used to shorthand ;-)

Comment: If you want to emphasize the _scalar_ nature of it, then you could specify a subset of $\mathbb F_p$ or $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, but for good reasons the original advice around it was just the _function on bit strings_ X25519(secret, public), which internally interprets the bit strings as scalars and curve points in a particular way.  Application developers are unlikely to make good choices—or do much more than have their eyes glaze over—when confronted with spaces like $\mathbb Z/(2^{252} + \dots)\mathbb Z$ and $E(\mathbb F_p) \cup (x^{-1}[\mathbb F_p] \cap E(\mathbb F_{p^2}))$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74393/discussion-between-cypherfox-and-squeamish-ossifrage).